# Android test failing when using rx chaining

Tags: rx-java, android-room

`dao.insert(position)` returns `Unit` ("`Void`"), `dao.getPosition()` returns `Single<IssPosition>`. `dbFailingTest` fails with following exception `Query returned empty result set: SELECT * FROM iss_position LIMIT 1` (but it doesn't really matter if I change the parameters to, say, `id = 1`). I'm using Room.

Why the first test is failing and the second one not? I believe them to be equivalent, but they're clearly not. I want my code eventually to look more like the failing test, because in my repo I'll be subscribing to some external events as well.

```
@Test
fun dbFailingTest() {
    Completable
            .fromCallable { dao.insert(position) }
        //    .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .to {
                dao.getPosition()
            }
            .test()
           // .awaitDone(1200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .assertResult(position)
}

@Test
fun dbPassingTest() {
    dao.insert(position)
    dao.getPosition()
            .test()
            .assertResult(position)
}
```

Comment: Add some logging to the test. I think that the order of execution is not as you would expect. RxJava might evaluate some expressions earlier.

Comment: also there is no need to wait in the first example, when fixed acc. to @Slav answer - see commented lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `to` converts `Completable` to something else, without waiting for the former to be completed. It just executes the function passed as an argument, using the `Completable` as an argument.

On the other hand, if you used `Single`:

```
@Test
fun dbFailingTest() {
    Single
            .fromCallable { dao.insert(position) }
            .flatMapMaybe { dao.getPosition() }
            .test()
            .assertResult(position)
}
```

`flatMapMaybe` converts the **result** of the `Single`, so it must necessarily wait for the `Single` to be completed.

Also, if you use `InstantTaskExecutorRule` in your test class:

```
@Rule
@JvmField
val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

this code should work:

```
@Test
fun dbFailingTest() {
    dao.insert(position)
    dao.getPosition()
        .test()
        .assertResult(position)
}
```

Comment: Slav - your answer does not explain why the first test is failing :)

Comment: @Klapsa2503, the test is failing because function `to` converts `Completable` to something else, without waiting for the former to be completed. It just executes the lambda with the `Completable` as an argument.

On the other hand, `flatMapMaybe` converts the **result** of the `Single` (so it must wait for the `Single` to be completed).

Comment: for `dbFailingTest` this works, but with the caveat that I'm just `flatMap`ping `dao.getPosition()` result (which is Single).  Then both `Single` and `Maybe`, that replaced `Completable`, worked.